# "The leaders were seated [in/on] the apse" - which one is better?

Tags: grammar

In the context of a cathedral/church. "The leaders were seated in the apse" or "The leaders were seated on the apse". Which one of these is right?

Comment: +1 for a contraversal question, can you give more context, eg *the building was a semi circle shaped auditorium and* **the leaders were seated ...**

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

"In the apse." An apse is a recess so think of it like a cave, for a more extreme representation. A cave is a recess into a structure. You wouldn't say "On the cave" if you were in it. If it were elevated, however, it would be a different situation.

Comment: Right. Apses are 3-dimensional concave spaces, or "containers". _In_ is used with container objects, like _yards_ or _bags_ or _minds_. _On_, however, refers to 2-dimensional objects, like _lawns_ or _tables_ or _checkerboards_.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is right, because apse isn't a place or mark on the map, apse is a semi-circular or polygonal termination of the main building.